# whitelabel error while calling java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=file:///Users/home/config/jdbc.properties from cmd

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting white label error. when I am trying following command:

```
java -jar ExcelUtility.jar  --spring.config.location=C:/Users/admin/Desktop/application-dev.properties
```

I have created batch file which includes following commands :

```
mvn clean install

mvn spring-boot:run  -Dspring.config.location="C:/Users/admin/Desktop/application-dev.properties"
```

it works fine

but when I am trying it using jar file like,

```
java -jar ExcelUtility.jar  --spring.config.location=C:/Users/admin/Desktop/application-dev.properties
```

Its not working, as I am getting white label error.

Comment: Can you try `java -jar -Dspring.config.location=C:/Users/admin/Desktop/application-dev.properties ExcelUtility.jar` ?

Comment: I have tried above command, but still same error